# Firestores 10 000 writes/second limitation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, limit, scalability

I am building an app using firestore at the moment. Google is always promoting firestore for its  scalability, but I don't think a [10 000 writes/second limit](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#limits) fits that promise. If you store user likes, notifications and what not in firestore you can easily exceed that limitation i guess. Is there something I am missing? Does this limit only apply to new documents or also to updates of documents?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question may not follow the guidelines of the SO, because it talks about a hypothetical situation and does not provide examples of what you've already tried. E.g. a good description would start with: "I'm hitting the limit of 10K req/sec and the requests to the DB get throttled." People seek for concrete problems and concrete solutions, but not for hypothetical advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore is made for hugely scalable **read** operations. Specifically, its main claim to fame is that running the a specific query will take a fixed amount of time, no matter how much data is in the collection(s) that you're querying. So if you're reading 10 documents from a collection that contains 10K documents and it takes (say) 1 second, you're guaranteed that the same read (under the same client conditions) will take 1 second when there's 10M documents or 10B documents in that collection.

The **write** throughput limits for Cloud Firestore are mostly determined by physical limitations. The 10K documents/sec is one, but you're more likely to encounter the limit of being able to write to each document roughly once per second. The reason fro these limits lies in Firestore's other guarantees. For example: Firestore guarantees immediate consistence of your write operations; so that once the write operation completes, no client will be getting older data from the server. To allow this it has to update to all indexes for the data in multiple data centers before confirming the write, which simply takes a certain amount of time, which in turn leads to the limits it has on write throughput. Similarly there are other limits that stem from these choices.

If you need higher write throughput and are willing to accept different performance guarantees, you may want to look for another database that meets those needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Interesting perspective. I guess I am going to choose another database engine then. I used a cache as workaround for the 1 write per second limit on documents which aggregates data before writing first, so that wouldn't have been a problem. But the 10K write limit seems like it will be easily exceeded.

Answer (score 7):

As of October 17, 2022, **Firestore** has no longer a [limit on the number of writes](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes#October_17_2022).

Comment: I think this should be updated as the new right answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with GCP offerings, but my experience with other clouds tells that you can do these things:

1. Make sure that you chose the right database. From the descriptions, it sounds that you need a NoSQL DB with auto-partitioning and eventual consistency.
2. The documentation says "Standard Limits" meaning that you can contact technical support that may extend the limits. At least this is how Azure works.
3. Cloud vendors provide consulting to make sure that their customers are successful with the technologies. Do you have such a channel? Have you talked to your CTO?
4. If GCP services don't meet your requirements, you may look at other database engines that you can host in the cloud with GKE. The cost of the initial setup and operations is higher but pays off in the long term. E.g. I went with this idea and hosted ElasticSearch in Azure, which turned out to be the best decision compared to available alternatives.

These tips may not exactly answer your question, but I hope that sharing my experience may help in finding the wholistic solution.

Comment: Great answer Serge!

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I am going to take your tips into consideration.